# Remove the reverse arrow in smartdiagram

Tags: arrows, smartdiagram

This is a simple example of a smartdiagram.

```
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{A,B,C,D}
```

[image]

How do I remove the pink arrow starting from D to A?

Comment: `back arrow disabled=true,` Have you taken a look into the manual?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.